# What are the risks of running a software RAID 1 array in degraded mode?

Tags: linux, raid-1, mdadm

I'm replacing my workstation's system drive and would like to in the future be able to easily add a second drive to form a proper (although software) RAID 1 mirror. For the time being, however, I'm only installing one drive.

If I use Linux MD to configure the single drive as a RAID 1 array of two devices but with one device missing, for example by [following a portion of this guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Convert_a_single_drive_system_to_RAID#Create_the_RAID_device), what (if any) *other than the fact that I won't have any redundancy* are the risks of such a setup? Am I likely to encounter any issues that I would not by simply using the disk as-is with no RAID involved at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, for all intents and purposes it will just be a single drive (using RAID1 as you plan). You would be able to pull the drive out and install it in another system wihtout mdadm and read it just fine.

Lack of redundancy is the only issue.

Answer (score 2):

There are no extra risks. You can use it this way.